# Firestore compound query with <= & >=

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query a firestore collection for entries where a start time (which is a number) is `>= slot.start` and and `<= slot.end`.

like this:

```js
.collection('Entries', ref => ref
    .where('timeStart', '>=', slot.timeStart)
    .where('timeEnd', '<=', slot.timeEnd))
```

but I get this error:

`Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field.`

I thought this query would work with composite index but as the error says that does not work.

When I change the query to this:

```js
.collection('Entries', ref => ref
    .where('timeStart', '==', slot.timeStart)
    .where('timeEnd', '<=', slot.timeEnd))
```

I can create an index for it. Furthermore when I change the 2nd '<=' to an '==' aswell I don't even need an index for it.

I didn't think my query is that advanced and I'm a little bit disappointed that firestore can't do this query. So what is the best solution for my problem? Is the next best thing to omit the 2nd query statement like this

```
.collection('Entries', ref => ref.where('timeStart', '>=', slot.timeStart))
```

And then iterate through the results and check if `timeEnd <= entry.timeEnd` "manually"? That seems like a really bad solution for me because I may need to load a lot of data then.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're going to have to pick one field and query that one then filter out the other on the client side. [Compound Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) documentation is firm on this one.

> **You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field**, and you can include at most one array_contains clause in a
>   compound query:

Comment: Hm that sucks :/. But I guess I have no other choice. Thanks anyways!

Comment: sucks big time, i love how we are being told to go no sql that the way, & here a simple query we cant get across

Comment: Yeah but the constraints also make it impossible to write inefficient queries...it's a win in my book

Comment: This is the first time I'm using firestore and I think it will be the last time. This is a big flaw in firestore. How did they think devs would use filters and queries

Comment: Hey, Firestore team, your query SUCKS

Answer (score 0):

In case this can be helpful, I was receiving the same error from this Flutter code, because of `media_state`:

```
  static Query<Media> getMediaByPlaceDayQuery(Place place, DateTime day) {
    return mediaCollectionRef
        .where("place_ref", isEqualTo: place.ref)
        .where("media_state",
            isNotEqualTo: MediaState.unsaved)
        .where("capture_time_epoch",
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: day.startOfDay.millisecondsSinceEpoch)
        .where("capture_time_epoch",
            isLessThanOrEqualTo: day.endOfDay.millisecondsSinceEpoch)
        .orderBy('capture_time_epoch');
  }
```

I solved it with this workaround:

```
static Query<Media> getMediaByPlaceDayQuery(Place place, DateTime day) {
    return mediaCollectionRef
        .where("place_ref", isEqualTo: place.ref)
        .where("media_state",
            whereIn: MediaState.values
                .where((state) => state != MediaState.unsaved)
                .map((state) => state.name)
                .toList())
        .where("capture_time_epoch",
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: day.startOfDay.millisecondsSinceEpoch)
        .where("capture_time_epoch",
            isLessThanOrEqualTo: day.endOfDay.millisecondsSinceEpoch)
        .orderBy('capture_time_epoch');
  }
```

---

So basically I converted

`isNotEqualTo` -> X

into

`whereIn` -> [everything but X].

Answer (score -5):

Perhaps it wasn't the case in 2018, but now you can create indexes that will allow queries with multiple `where`s.

Firebase calls those "Composite indexes"
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes

Find the "Indexes" tab in the Firebase admin, create what you need and profit.

[image: screenshot showing where the "indexes" button is in firebase's web interface]

This code is taken [straight from the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_single-field_indexes):

```js
citiesRef.where("country", "==", "USA")
         .where("capital", "==", false)
         .where("state", "==", "CA")
         .where("population", "==", 860000)
```

Comment: Read [Compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries)